# Safe way to share file with data between java and javascript

Tags: javascript, java

I have a file containing a very small amount of data which is being updated every 10 ms by my java program.

Would it be safe to read that file simultaneously in my javascript program?

Comment: In general, if there is only one process writing to the file, then you should be good.please add more context and some code to get more detailed answer

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Writing to a file every 10ms just to share it with another program isn't exactly efficient. I'd recommend using a socket instead.

Comment: So if only 1 process is writing the file, there should be no problem with reading it at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your operation system and the reading/writing software that accesses the file. If the file is locked because you try to access it in the very small time window while it is written, your read could fail. In that case you simply should build a loop, that tries again to open the file until it has success.

More about file locking: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking

Instead you could also use a socket or a database.